# How to avoid space here

Tags: spacing, horizontal-alignment, matrices

I am getting an empty Here as you can see, how to avoid it[image]

```
\documentclass[reqno]{amsart}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{etoolbox} 

$\begin{matrix}
T(X_1,X_2)(t)& \subset& \left\{\int_{0}^{t} K(t, s) f(s, x(s),y(s)) d s: \; x\in X_1,\,y\in X_2\right\} \\
\\ 
&\subset& t.\,\overline{conv}\Big(\left\{ f(s, x(s),y(s)) d s: \; x\in X_1,\,y\in X_2,\: s \in[0, t]\right\}\Big) \\ 
\\
&\subset& t.\,\overline{conv}\Big(f(I\times X_1\times X_2)\Big) .
\end{matrix}$
By \ref{CApp},  we conclude  \[\begin{matrix}
\beta \Big(T(X_1,X_2)(t)\Big) &\leq&  t. \beta\big(f(I \times X_1\times X_2)\big)\\
&\leq& \max \{\beta(X_1),\beta(X_2)\}-\delta  \Big(\max \{\beta(X_1),\beta(X_2)\}\Big)\,.  
\end{matrix}\]



\end{document}
```

Comment: Without the code, it's difficult to guess the underlying reason. See the comment from David Carlisle on one of your previous questions (https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/523312).

Comment: Could you provide your source code? We can't help you otherwise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guessing, that you are after following:

[image]

```
\documentclass[reqno]{amsart}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
    \begin{align*}
T(X_1,X_2)(t)
    & \subset \left\{\int_{0}^{t} K(t,s) f(s,x(s),y(s)) d s:\; 
            x\in X_1,\,y\in X_2\right\} \\
    &\subset t.\,\overline{conv}\bigl(\left\{ f(s,x(s),y(s)) d s: \; 
            x\in X_1,\,y\in X_2,\: s \in[0, t]\right\}\bigr)           \\
    &\subset t.\,\overline{conv}\bigl(f(I\times X_1\times X_2)\bigr) . \\
\intertext{By \ref{CApp}, we conclude}  
\beta \big(T(X_1,X_2)(t)\big) 
    &\leq t. \beta\big(f(I \times X_1\times X_2)\big)                   \\
    &\leq \max \bigl\{\beta(X_1),\beta(X_2)\bigr\}-\delta  \bigl(\max \{\beta(X_1),\beta(X_2)\}\bigr)\,.
    \end{align*}
\end{document}
```

As you see, in above MWE (Minimal Working Example) is used  `align*` math environment, which is designed for similar purposes.